# Is it possible to declare a variable type from string?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I don't know the technical term for this.I am wondering in Objective C, if it is possible to declare a variable like this:

```
NSClassFromString(aClassName) *var;
```

or

```
[NSClassFromString(aClassName) class] *var;
```

Apparently, the above two are not correct. What I want is to dynamically declare a variable.
Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should make the ivar of `id` type, and then make it dynamically typed. For example, if you want to dynamically type it `NSString`, you can do like this :

```
id ivar;
Class myClass = NSClassFromString(@"NSString");

ivar = [[myClass alloc] initWithString:@"abc"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to declare `var` as an `id`, and then instantiate it like:

```
var = [[NSClassFromString(aClassName) alloc] init];
```

The only point of declaring a type is compile-time type-checking, so there shouldn't be a problem as long as you only throw messages at the object that it can handle.

Answer (score 1):

`id` is they type of a dynamically typed variable. If you need to check to see if a variable conforms to a particular class you can use `-isKindOfClass:`.

You can dynamically test if a class is some type with `[var isKinkdOfClass:NSClassFromString(aClassName)]`